# Only Receive Mail at Set Times in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'd like to be able to configure Thunderbird to only retrieve messages from an IMAP server at specific times of the day - 9am, 11am, 2pm and 4pm. I'd like the sending of emails to be possible at all times, however.

Is there a native setting in Thunderbird that allows this, or an addon that adds this functionality?

If this isn't possible, are there alternative email clients available for Windows 7 and 8 that allow this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) and [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) are command line programs that can retrieve your email so you could run those commands from a scheduled job in your operating system. However on Windows you'll probably need an environment like Cygwin to run them.